# React component behaves differently in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox

I have written a React component `Tooltipable` that is able to wrap another component and display a tooltip for it.

It works well in Firefox. However, in Chrome - sometimes - when element is hovered onto, the tooltip display is not consistent.

Can someone explain this behavior and also advise how it can be corrected? I believe it is not really related to React, just the way I have approached the problem and/or the way those two browsers render stuff.

Here is a CodePen:

https://codepen.io/barciewicz/pen/MWpNJoy?editors=1000

Comment: Simple improvement is to add an `if` statement around your `mouseEvent` handlers - if already visible, don't re-set that component to visible again...

There is a logic issue though. There is only one tooltip component shown at a time - so why do you have to return one for every list item? You'll find performance upgrades if you focus on showing/hiding/updating a single component rather than all of them - currently every time a change happens, every tooltip component must change too

Comment: @MikeAbeln it may seem like that, but actually, React handles all that optimizations for you. When you set a state to the same value, React discards that value and keeps the old one. There is only one tooltip at a time (when an instance returns `null` it is not rendered) and in any case, they would be all instances of the same component. The whole purpose of React is to split your App into as many small components as possible and to narrow the scope of your state as much as possible. If you respect React basic rules, you'll be fine.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano Good explanations, thanks! I overlooked the ternary statement at the bottom of the Tooltip component. Your point #4 below explains the glitch well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example.

I did the following:

1. Replaced `mouseover` with `mousemove`.
2. Replaced `mouseout` with `mouseleave`.
3. Fixed list markup (`li` should be a direct children of `ul`. You can avoid using the list with `Flexbox` or other techniques and it should still work).
4. I just added some space between the cursor and the tooltip (I added 5px, but 1px should do the trick too). If you don't do this, `mouseleave` event would fire on the text element each time the tooltip appears (creating the glitchy effect you noticed).

```js
const Tooltip = ({x, y, content, visible}) => {
    const style = {
        position: 'fixed',
        left: x + 'px',
        top: y + 'px',
        background: 'black',
        color: 'white',
        padding: '.5%'
    };
    const tooltip = <span style={style}>{content}</span>;
    return visible ? tooltip : null;
};

const Tooltipable = ({component, tooltipContent}) => {
    const [tooltipXy, setTooltipXy] = React.useState({x: 0, y: 0});
    const [tooltipVisible, setTooltipVisible] = React.useState(false);

    const handleMouseOver = (e) => {
        setTooltipXy({x: e.clientX + 5, y: e.clientY + 5});
        setTooltipVisible(true);
    };

    const handleMouseOut = () => {
        setTooltipVisible(false);
    };

    return (
        <li>
            <span
                style={{background: 'pink'}}
                onMouseLeave={handleMouseOut}
                onMouseMove={handleMouseOver}>
                {component}
            </span>
            <Tooltip
                x={tooltipXy.x}
                y={tooltipXy.y}
                content={tooltipContent}
                visible={tooltipVisible}
            />
        </li>
    );
};

const Todos = ({todos}) => (
    <ul>
        {todos.map((todo, index) => {
            const component = (
                <span style={{background: 'powderblue', display: 'inline'}}>
                    {todo.text}
                </span>
            );
            return (
                <Tooltipable
                    key={index}
                    component={component}
                    tooltipContent={'Created ' + todo.createdOn}
                />
            );
        })}
    </ul>
);

const App = () => {
    const todos = [
        {text: 'clean car', createdOn: 'yesterday'},
        {text: 'fix windows', createdOn: 'two days ago'},
        {text: 'go shopping', createdOn: 'today'},
        {text: 'meet family', createdOn: 'five days ago'},
        {text: 'clean car', createdOn: 'yesterday'},
        {text: 'fix windows', createdOn: 'two days ago'},
        {text: 'go shopping', createdOn: 'today'},
        {text: 'meet family', createdOn: 'five days ago'},
        {text: 'clean car', createdOn: 'yesterday'},
        {text: 'fix windows', createdOn: 'two days ago'},
        {text: 'go shopping', createdOn: 'today'},
        {text: 'meet family', createdOn: 'five days ago'},
        {text: 'clean car', createdOn: 'yesterday'},
        {text: 'fix windows', createdOn: 'two days ago'},
        {text: 'go shopping', createdOn: 'today'},
        {text: 'meet family', createdOn: 'five days ago'}
    ];
    return <Todos todos={todos} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

</head>
  
<body>
  <div id="root">
</body>

</html>
```